# Restoring presentation server Shared Folder - OBIEE 11g

Tags: obiee

By mistake I deleted the shared folder from catalog (/analytics), what options do I have now. I have OBIEE 11.1.1.9 installation on linux server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by re-creating the catalog from scratch,
following below steps: 

1. Go to `<obi_installation>\instances\instance1\config\OracleBIPresentationServicesComponent\coreapplication_obips1`

2. Open your `instanceconfig.xml` file

3. Find `<CatalogPath>` and `</CatalogPath>` tags

4. Write the new catalong name that you want to create (suppose xyz) then your tag should look like this

```
<CatalogPath><obi_installation>\instances\instance1/bifoundation/OracleBIPresentationServicesComponent/coreapplication_obips1/catalog/xyz</CatalogPath>
```

5. Save the file and start/re-start the BI presentation service (using opmnctl is faster)

6. It automatically creates the "xyz" catalog, once we start our presentation service and you need not to create anything manually..

Comment: Creating a new catalog is not a good solution for deleting your old one. As always, good backups are the only solution for a data loss scenario. Creating a new catalog will also mean that data in the users directory is lost or will need recovering, compounding your loss of the shared directory.

Comment: Thanks for your input @jackohug it was my development box where it happened out of accident.